# Solving mathematical differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I am struggling in solving this differential equation:

$$b'(x)=b(x)^{2}\: +\: b(x)\ln(b(x))(K-\gamma ).$$

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming $K$ and $\gamma$ are just numbers, the equation is autonomous so it suffices to be able to evaluate $\int \frac{db}{b^2+b \ln(b)}$ to get an implicit solution. That integral isn't elementary, though, so its inverse probably isn't either.

Comment: Recommendation for new contributor:  Do you see why $(K - \gamma)$ is just another constant (call it $C$)?  You should always post the *minimal* question that contains the core of your question.  In doing so it might help you solve it yourself.  Regardless, it makes it easier for those who might want to help you.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you can write it as $u' = e^u+cu$ by using $u(x)=\log b(x)$.

Comment: Dear All, thank you for your help. You are right, I obmitted to specify that $K$ and $\gamma$ are constants. I will keep in my mind for the future to group all the constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence of log y renders analytically solving it impossible, so a numerical solution is suggested with one differentiation ( primes with respect to $x$ )  to raise ODE order to two, eliminating constant $(K-\gamma).$

Also it is customary to use $(a,b,c)$ for constants. Let $ y(x)= b(x)$ and let primes denote differentiation with respect to $x$. Employ Chain Rule..

$$\dfrac{y'/y-y}{\log\,y}=\dfrac{\dfrac{{yy''-y^{'2}}}{y^2}-1}{\dfrac{1}{y}}$$

$$ RHS=y''-\dfrac{y^2+y^{'2}}{y}$$

so the ODE is:

$$ y''= y+y^{'2}/y + \dfrac{y'/y-y}{\log\,y}$$

can be integrated with convenient boundary conditions:

$$ x=0,y=1, y'=1. $$